# result_of fails to deduce return type

Tags: c++, templates, types, type-traits

The following code fails to compile in GCC 5.2:

```
template<typename FuncType, typename... ArgTypes>
result_of_t<FuncType(ArgTypes...)> FuncCall(const FuncType &f, ArgTypes&... args)
{
    return f(forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
}

string SomeFunc()
{
    return "SomeFunc";
}

int main()
{
    cout << FuncCall([](){return "Lambda";}) << "\n"; // This call works properly
    cout << FuncCall(SomeFunc) << "\n"; // this call fails
}
```

But if I change the following line:

```
result_of_t<FuncType(ArgTypes...)> FuncCall(const FuncType &f, ArgTypes&... args)
```

To

```
result_of_t<FuncType&&(ArgTypes...)> FuncCall(const FuncType &f, ArgTypes&... args)
```

Then it works properly.

I don't understand how making FuncType rvalue reference in this case solves the problem. Can anyone share some light on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function type in C++ may not have a return type that is a function type, by [dcl.fct]/10:

> Functions shall not have a return type of type array or function, although they may have a return type of type pointer or reference to such things.

So when `FuncType` is deduced as a function type, the purported type `FuncType(Args...)` is ill-formed.